# Preview items are showing in search

Tags: catalog, catalogsearch

We need items scheduled for Preview to be secret. Right now if something is scheduled for a preview a week in the future, it still shows for customers when they search for a word in the title. We need to keep preview items off of the website until after they expire from preview. I'm not even sure where to start with troubleshooting this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok so in product select visibility to only catalog then your item will not come in search results page

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment above, the solution is to set the product visibility to "only catalog". The will prevent the product from showing up in search.

Comment: After having more time to work with this deployment it appears the previous developers added custom status codes aside from Enabled and Disabled, so they did not behave as normal in this regard like they were designed to. This solution still applies to both scenarios and setting the item to Only Catalog or None will produce the same result of removing them from the search results.